# Can't figure out how to properly upload file with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text-files

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to create an app in which the landing page allows a user to upload a `.txt` file. I'm running into a problem where the data isn't being loaded properly because of how I have it, the page is looking for the data before the user uploads a file. I cannot figure out how to properly do this? If someone could show me or point me in the right direction in terms of resources, that would be incredibly helpful.

Here are my four files:

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="resume_uploader">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Resume Builder</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap css and my own css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div ng-controller="resumeCtrl as resume">
    <input type=file id=files />
    <button id=upload>Upload</button><br>
        {{resume.text}}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/dataservice.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/resume.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`app.js`:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("resume_uploader", []);
})();
```

`resume.js`:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("resume_uploader")
        .controller("resumeCtrl", ResumeController);

    ResumeController.$inject =['DataService'];

    function ResumeController(DataService) {
        this.DataService = DataService;
        this.text = DataService.processFile;
    }
})();
```

`dataservice.js`:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("resume_uploader")
        .factory("DataService", DataService);

function DataService() {
    var dataObj = {
        processFile: processFile()
        //TODO: Data Parse
    };
    return dataObj;
}

var fileInput = $('#files');
var uploadButton = $('#upload');

uploadButton.on('click', function() {
    if(!window.FileReader) {
        alert('Your browser is not supported')
    }
    var input = fileInput.get(0);

    // Create a reader object
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if(input.files.length) {
        var textFile = input.files[0];
        reader.readAsText(textFile);
        $(reader).on('load', processFile);
    } else {
        alert('Please upload a file before continuing')
    }
});

function processFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.result,
        results;
    if(file && file.length) {
        results = file.split("\n");
        }
        return results;
    }
})();
```

Any and all help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Most of this code isn't even angular, it's JQuery.

Comment: @Claies I guess I meant just by how the app is set up then.

Comment: if you want to use angular, the first step should be to get rid of the `on('click')` calls and replace them with the appropriate angular equivalent `ng-click`.  if you still have issues, then post your updated code.  `on('click')` isn't angular aware, so angular will never know that the click happened or that it needs to change any bindings as a result of the function call.

Comment: @Claies Awesome. I'll go down that path and report back if I need more help. Thanks!